# How to write complexity of a program using big Oh notation?

Tags: python-3.x

Taken from "MITx: 6.00.1x Introduction to Computer Science and Programming Using Python".

I am doing this course and during solving quiz I have problem. I am very new programmer and I do not have enough idea of programming.

> What is the number of steps it will take to run Program 2 in the worst case? Express your answer in terms of n, the size of the input x.
>
> ```
>  def program2(x):
>     total = 0
>     for i in range(1000):
>         total = i
>
>     while x > 0:
>         x = x//2
>         total += x
>
>     return total
> ```

Comment: Have you tried something yourself ?

Comment: Yes dear friend, I did my self but that is not right.

3+1000+5*n

as rest of things are constant so 5n would be the answer but 5 is again constant so O(n) would be answer.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your program to get answer from itself

```
def program(x):
    count = 0
    while x > 0:
        x = x // 2
        count += 1
    return count
```

> x = 2 ** 31 => count = 32
>
> x = 2 ** 10 => count = 11

. . .

Result: `O(log n)`

Answer (score 0):

In the best case scenario, x is less than or equal to 0. We first execute the assignment total = 0 for one step. Next we execute the for i in range(1000) loop. This loop is executed 1000 times and has three steps (one for the assignment of i each time through the loop, as well as two for the += operation) on each iteration. We next check if x > 0 - it is not so we do not enter the loop. Adding one more step for the return statement, in the best case we execute 1 + 3*1000 + 1 + 1 = 3003 steps.

In the worst case scenario, x is a large positive number. In this case, we first execute the assignment total = 0 for one step. Next we execute the first loop 1000 times (3000 total steps), then we execute the second loop (while x > 0) n times. This loop has five steps (one for the conditional check, x > 0, and two each for the -= and += operations). When we finally get to the point where x = 0, we execute the conditional check x > 0 one last time - since it is not, we do not enter the loop. Adding one more step for the return statement, in the worst case we execute 1 + 3*1000 + 5*n + 1 + 1 = 5*n + 3003 steps.